# Hyphen between 2 words when prefix is in front of the 2 words

Tags: hyphenation, prefixes, affixes

What's the correct way to put a prefix in front of something that's 2 or more words?

Pre-Neolithic Revolution or pre-Neolithic-Revolution

Pro-affirmative action or pro-affirmative-action

Post-Civil War or post-Civil-War

Non-high school or non-high-school (student)

Answer (score 1):

With a single hyphen, you have an adjective and a noun. When you hyphenate throughout, the multiply-hyphenated term is an adjective.

To use one of your examples:

- a *post-civil war* is a war (noun) that is no longer (‘post’) civil (adjective); whereas
- a *post-civil-war landscape* is a landscape following a civil war.

In these constructions, the words in the hyphenated compound modify each other. For example, post” modifies “civil war”, and “civil” modifies “war”.

Comment: I've been unable to find any authoritative guidance on this, but my instinct would be to use _post-Civil War_ etc. Surely no-one would interpret that as meaning 'a war that is no longer civil'?

Comment: Yes, context can help disambiguate, but the principle holds.